# IBM Message broker: how to unsetldap princial and credentials

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

Using mqsichangebroker I'm able to set the ldap username and password. Is there a way to unset this once made? I've managed to unset the principal by passing `-y """"` but the credential cannot be set to the same as it asks for a password.

```
mqwmb@esbprodz > mqsichangebroker ESBTST -y """" -z """"

Enter password for user ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete and recreate the broker and fail to specify the `-y` and `-z`.  Which you really kind of should do anyway, and then use `mqsisetdbparms` to specify the credentials instead.

Then you can use the `-d` flag on `mqsisetdbparms` to remove the credentials at a later date.

Comment: Ah, so what is the difference between the ldap crendentials option with mqsichangebroker and the mqsisetdbparms. Are there different uses with these?

Answer (score 0):

You could also stop the broker and  delete the $MQSI_REGISTRY/registry//CurrentVersion/LdapCredentials and LdapPrincipal files.